# C++ freeing heap-allocated variables in functions

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management, scope

Here's part of a function:

```
std::queue<std::string>* shunting_yard(std::vector<std::string> input){
    std::queue<std::string>* output = new std::queue<std::string>();
    ...
    return output;
```

I've dynamically allocated queue `output` is pointing to on the heap. However, when I try to free/delete the queue in `int main()` I get an error because `output` is declared out of scope.

Considering the fact that I'm returning `output` in the above function- so I can't free it inside the function- how can I make sure that there is not a memory leak? One potential solution I've thought of would be declaring `std::queue<std::string>* output` in the global scope and `output = new std::queue<std::string>()` inside the function, but are there any other solutions to this out of scope error?

Comment: `std::unique_ptr`. But there isn't really a reason to dynamically allocate an `std::queue`, as its storage itself is, in turn, dynamically allocated. Just return the value.

Comment: @Quentin I decided to return a pointer to it because I wanted to check if it was a NULL pointer (in case anything went wrong inside the function). Is this a valid reason?

Comment: No. If something goes wrong and the function cannot return a sensible result, throw an exception.

Comment: And if exception doesn't make sense (as in the failure to produce a good result is not an exceptional event) use [`std::optional`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional). You could also return a `std::pair` of `std::queue` and `bool`. Set the `bool` to `true` if the result is acceptable.

Comment: Generalization: [Why should C++ programmers minimize use of 'new'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6500313/why-should-c-programmers-minimize-use-of-new)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not delete variables, or pointers. You delete things you allocate with `new`. The line:

```
std::queue<std::string>* output = new std::queue<std::string>();
```

does not allocate a variable called `output` with `new`. It allocates a queue, which has no name, and creates a local variable called `output`, and stores the address of the queue into the local variable `output`.

This line:

```
return output;
```

returns the address of the queue. Because it also ends the function, the local variable `output` is destroyed (just like all local variables). The caller receives the address.

How do you call this function? You didn't show that code, but it's something like:

```
std::queue<std::string>* woof = shunting_yard(meow);
```

In this case, this creates a new local variable in the caller, called `woof`, which now holds the address of the queue that `shunting_yard` created.

You can delete the queue by passing its address to `delete`. Its address is stored in the variable `woof`. So you can write `delete woof;`. The fact that the address was stored in a different variable is irrelevant, as long as the address is the same.

---

More advanced programmers will use `std::unique_ptr<std::queue<std::string>>`. But I recommend learning to do `new` and `delete` by hand *first*, before learning `unique_ptr`, so that you'll understand what `unique_ptr` actually does.

Really advanced programmers will realize they don't `new` at all, and just use `std::queue<std::string>` (no pointer).